# windows phone C# system.web

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, libraries, system.web

I am trying to follow this article:

http://chriskoenig.net/2011/08/19/upload-files-from-windows-phone/

but when I am writing:

`using System.Web.Mvc;`

but it seems not to find:

```
using system.web
```

I am looking for the libraries to add it manually but I can't find it,
any suggestions?

It seems that I have to download some extra DLLs but I am not sure where I will find secure copies of them?

Comment: Are you writing a web application or an app for windows phone? System.Web.Mvc is used to develop a web application running on a web server. You cant use it on Windows phone. MVC framework is available at http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: ooo i also forgot tot say that it is for windows phone 7.5

Comment: Then you can't use MVC. This is for server side. The code posted in your example is server side code.

Comment: http://chriskoenig.net/2011/08/19/upload-files-from-windows-phone/

so file FileController.cs is going on windos server ?? :O or on windows phone ??

Comment: Windows server. the 2nd code snippet is for windows phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the tutorial states `Here’s my Controller (FileController.cs)` he is talking about the server-side application. Not the Windows Phone application. WP7 does not have this library available.

If you are working in the server-side application you can find System.Web (when adding a reference) under the `.NET` tab.